# is it okay to accelerate in gear 'B'?

Tags: toyota, automatic-transmission

I have a toyota Yaris 2017. All the gears I have are P,R,N,D,B. I don't know what really the gear 'B' stands for, but i think it means 'Engine break' when going in slopes to avoid using brakes all the time.

Problem is I sometimes forget to change gear 'B' to 'D' when I am accelerating after a slope and go some distance without understanding. I only undertand it when i feel the engine is not accelerating as it used to. So my questions are,

1.What is really gear 'B' stands for?

2.Did I damage my engine or gear box by accelerating for some distances in gear 'B'?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"B" on Toyota CVT transmissions is indeed the "Engine braking" mode - it effectively simulates using lower gears in a traditional transmission to allow for more engine braking, which is useful for downhill travel to prevent excessive wear on the brakes and for preventing rollback during slow travel uphill.

It won't damage your car doing what you describe but it's not offering any benefit to do so (and in fact is probably detrimental to fuel economy slightly).

Answer (score 0):

Well, found this manual, but while is says it is for 2010 to present - it does not match the gears you state you have, may give you an idea though.

http://www.toyaris.com/automatic_transmission-327.html